Why pyodbc connection.close hangs for 10 minute after timeout error on Azure-sql-database?
I'm executing the following code. The code intentionally contains a query that takes longer than the query timeout.
import pyodbc

TIMEOUT_SEC = 1
QUERY_DELAY_SEC = TIMEOUT_SEC + 1
DSN = ".."
QUERY = f"WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:{QUERY_DELAY_SEC:02d}';SELECT 1;"

conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN)
conn.timeout = TIMEOUT_SEC
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    result = cursor.execute(QUERY).fetchall()
    cursor.close()
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    # if timeout exception happens this close gets a ~10 min. wait
    # if query succeed (e.g. with removed `WAITFOR DELAY`), close is instant 
    conn.close();

print(f"{result=}")

I expect it

raises the timeout error
prints the error
exits the script

While instead it

raises the timeout error
prints the error
waits 10 minutes
exits the script

Can the expected behavior be forced somehow?

You probably have to set the connection timeout in .connect(DSN, timeout=3) function for that.

I did it, still nothing. Perhaps, because it sets the time limit for establishing the connection, so different case.

I ran into the same issue. Turns out to be a bug in the ODBC driver that has been fixed in version 18.4.1.1. ("Fix 10-minute delay upon disconnection after timeout")
